# MongoDB problems when using Guid string as primary key

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've imported some documents in a collection.
Example document:

```json
{
  "_id":"760a812e-7bd1-42f2-9892-75486e809655",
  "name":"John Doe"
}
```

My C# POCO class:

```cs
public class ProductCategory
{
   [BsonId]
   public string Id { get; set; }

   [BsonElement("name")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

When trying to filter I get an error message.
Filter code:

```cs
var collection = _client.GetDatabase("db").GetCollection<ProductCategory>("coll1");
var filter = Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, productCategory.Id);
```

Error Message:

```
"'760a812e-7bd1-42f2-9892-75486e809655' is not a valid 24 digit hex string."
```

Edit: I'm using Mongo C# driver v2.22 with .NET7

Comment: As per https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ it's supposed to be `A 24 character hexadecimal string value `

Comment: A GUID string is not BsonID.  From  : [BsonId] To : [BsonElement("_id")]

Comment: I want to use Guid string as ID. I do not want to use ObjectID.

Comment: @jdweng still not working. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<ProductCategory>("coll");
        var productCategory = new ProductCategory() { Name = "name", Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
        collection.InsertOne(productCategory);
        var filter = Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, productCategory.Id);
        var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

I assume the problem is quoted value, try removing **'**.

note: same result for this input date:

```
var productCategory = new ProductCategory() { Name = "name", Id = "760a812e-7bd1-42f2-9892-75486e809655" };
```

db record:

```
> db.coll.find()
{ "_id" : "760a812e-7bd1-42f2-9892-75486e809655", "name" : "name" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. However, this still does not work. It throws at `InsertOne` 
`An error occurred while serializing the Id property of class Model.ProductCategory: '7124bd90-7696-4d7f-8e9a-c0c3eb93b5e2' is not a valid 24 digit hex string`

Comment: I inserted and read data without any issue. Did you try my example?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried your sample in a simple Console App and it's working. Thanks. There must be another issue...

Comment: My issue was in another library. I'm using Mongo Repository https://github.com/johnknoop/MongoRepository